# Is it possible to use a table based on case statement?

Tags: sybase

I have a procedure which looks like this.

```
CREATE PRODEDURE get_count
    @rdr CHAR(3)
AS
    SELECT t.cnt FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, 'X' rdr  FROM table_X
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, 'Y' rdr FROM table_Y
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt , 'Z' rdr  FROM table_Z) t
    WHERE t.rdr = @rdr
```

Is it possible to use a case statement or some other Sybase trick that I am unaware of to optimize above procedure? So that, it uses the table_X when you pass in 'X', table_Y when you pass 'Y' and so on..The only motivation for optimization is because the individual count() operations take a lot of time and every time I make a call it comes to a standstill...

Comment: Why are there three separate tables?  Can you blow the records from those three tables into a new table, index the `rdr` field, and use that table instead?

Comment: The individual tables are huge. And this is the only procedure that needs this. Though, merging them is possible, it will be an overkill for just one procedure.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in two ways

1- add query in if else statement

if @var="X"
select count(*) from table_X

if @var="Y"
select count(*) from table_Y

if @var="Z"
select count(*) from table_Z

OR use dynamic SQL-- pass table name as input
declare @a varchar(30)
select @a= "table_name"
EXEC ("select count(*) from "+@a)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Run a SELECT COUNT query on each individual table and collect the counts.  Then add all the counts together to get the final result.

While this comes at the cost of running three queries instead of one, it eliminates the UNIONs and allows you to use an index on the `rdr` field for each table.